# GraphQL result conversion to Dict in Python

Tags: python, graphql

In python I'm querying a graphql API and getting a GraphQLResult datatype back.

I want to be able to iterate through the results to then feed back through the API within a mutation.

I thought I could dict(result) and bring back a dictionary but this just brings back a nicely formatted GraphQLResult result as a dict datatype!

```
result = client.graphql(
{
    'query': {
        'agent': {
            'id'
        }
    }
}
)

dres = (result)

print(dres)

print(dict(dres))
```

Which brings back this:

```
{'data': {
"agent": [
    {
        "id": "123"
    }
]
}}
```

I want to extract that ID and use it but know how/the best way, any ideas?

Comment: That final output looks like what I'd expect the [HTTP response](https://spec.graphql.org/October2021/#sec-Response) to look like; can you navigate it like an ordinary Python nested dictionaly, `dres['data']['agent'][0]['id']`?

Comment: I've since adjusted how I'd do this by converting the GraphQLResult  output to json and then using that to list out the elements which has worked exactly how I needed it.  Dict was the wrong approach as the next element in the dict was another key with a key of ID which dict didn't like!